# Eclipse project stored in SVN checkout in Android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, android-studio

I was using SVN with eclipse but now I switched to Android studio .. So I am trying to check out my project in android studio but getting

```
"Cannot load supported formats: Cannot run program "svn": error=2, No such file or directory android studio "
```

Pop up of this error. I updated my Android studio also but the same problem. I am getting:
   I am trying to checkout using:

```
 VCS-> Checkout from version control-> Subversion
```

in android studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just click on File->open settings->Click on version Control
Inside subversion uncheck "use command line client".
Now you will be able to checkout from SVN.